# c# dictionary as a value of a hashtable

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have to code a little C# Console application (but my knowledge on .NET is almost NULL) to make a POST request to a PHP API, for which I'm using an HttpClient instance. The API accepts a JSON like this

```
{
    "User": {
        "email": "email@host.com",
        "password": "something"
    },
    "Establishment": {
        "id": 147
    }
}
```

After doing some research on how to do this what I've done so far is this:

```
        static async Task RunAsync()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://italdelo.web.development.co/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                try
                {
                    // HTTP POST
                    Dictionary<string, string> user = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    Dictionary<string, int> establishment = new Dictionary<string, int>();
                    HashTable postdata = new HashTable();

                    user.Add("email","email@host.com");
                    user.Add("password","something");
                    establishment.Add("id",147);
                    postdata.Add("User",user);
                    postdata.Add("Establishment",establishment);


                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("apiname/service", postdata);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();    // Throw if not a success code.
                }
                catch (HttpRequestException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception details: " + e.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Running this code I got this error message:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'HashTable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ProjectName C:\Users\...\Program.cs 47  Active
```

I know the error is the way I'm trying to setup the JSON to send to the API, which is a hashtable containing values (hashtable's key-value notation) as dictionaries. I'm pretty sure this is dumb but I don't really know how to setup this JSON for the API, I have no choice, I need to use C#. Can you help me please giving me some advice on how to fix this or get this done in another way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A common way is to create objects (User, Establishment, etc.), then use Json.Net to serialize your objects. http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a class that will serve as parameter for consuming API.

```
//you classes
public class Parameter
{
  public User user { get; set;}
  public Establishment {get; set;}
}
public class User
{
    public string email {get; set;}
    public string password {get; set}
}

public class Establishment
{
    public int id {get;set;}
}
```

//in your api calling method:

```
`var p = new Parameter
        {
            Establishment = new Establishment
            {
                id = 123
            },
            User = new User
            {
                email = "email",
                password = "password"
            }
        };
```

`HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("apiname/service", p);`

Comment: Thank you @Jeric Cruz for your response, I wasn't lucky with your suggestion though, got this error: "Exception details: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 <Internal Server Error> in System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() in ProjectName.Program.<RunSync>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\RouteToProject.cs". However when I send a request to the API via Postman it works, so there is no problem with the API.I'd really appreciate some more help please. Thanks.

Comment: try to use PostAsync and add formatter MediaTypeFormatter formatter = new MyCustomFormatter();

Comment: var response = await client.PostAsync("apiname/service", p, formatter);

Comment: Thanks again Jeric for your reply, I realized there was a semicolon missing in the class User after the "set", so I fixed it and run it again and got this error this time: "Exception details: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 <Not Found> 
in System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() in ProjectName.Program.<RunSync>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\RouteToProject.cs". It looks like I am doing somethis wrong with the calling in  HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("apialdelo/getDeliverie", json);

Comment: My bad dude!!... There was a typo in the method name, I fixed it and it worked!!... I'm getting another type of errors now but I'll try to figure it out... Thank you for your help Jeric, pitifully they don't allow me to upvote your answer yet but this is the best. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use c# anonymous classes

```
var payload = new{
    User=new {
        email= "email@host.com",
        password= "something"
    },
    Establishment=new {
        id= 147
    }
}
```

then use newtonsoft json.net

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);
```

Comment: Thank you @pm100 for your response, nonetheless I tried out your suggestion and got this error: "Exception details: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 <Internal Server Error>". However when I send a request to the API via Postman it works, so there is no problem with the API. Had you seen this before? Thanks.

Comment: it means the server barfed on the request. If 'the same' request worsk with postman then there is a typo somewhere in your c# code copies from above. look at the json and copmpare it to the postman payload

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo, C# Hashtable does not capitalize the middle T:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You are right @Trasig Torsk. I made the correction but still not working.